# Trying to mutate vector value using integer reference?

Tags: rust

I am learning rust. I am trying to understand how the references work.

As per my understanding so far, the literal values likes string literals and numbers are pushed on to the stack and not on heap.

But I am trying to use the reference of a element of a vector and mutate it.

**expectation** -> The reference will mutate the value inside the vector

**reality** -> nothing happens

I know I am missing some major concept here but I'm trying it hard to wrap my around it.

```rust
    // creating a vector of i32 type
    let v = vec!(1, 2, 3, 4);

    // getting reference of the value at index 0
    let mut i = &v[0];
    
    // updating the referred value
    i = &69;
    
    // printing the vector values
    for x in v {
        println!("{}", x); 
        // prints   1,  2, 3, 4
        // and not  69, 2, 3, 4
    }
```

Comment: `i = &69` doesn't change the pointee, it just changes where `i` points to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are so close. This is how it is proper:

```rust
fn main() {
    // creating a vector of i32 type
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    // getting reference of the value at index 0
    let i = &mut v[0];

    // updating the referred value
    *i = 69;

    // printing the vector values
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

```
[69, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

**Explanation:**

In your original code, you did:

```rust
let mut i = &v[0];
```

which will create mutable variable with the type `&` (immutable reference). You cannot modify `v` through an immutable reference, so you need to do

```rust
let i = &mut v[0];
```

instead. This creates an immutable variable of the type `&mut` (mutable reference). This means the variable `i` itself cannot be modified, but the content it references can. Which is what you want.

In the next line, you then do

```rust
i = &69;
```

which modifies `i`, **not** the `v` vector! You basically create the value `69` somewhere and make `i` a reference to this one instead of the `v` vector.

If you want to modify the `v` vector through the `i` reference, you need to **dereference** it first via the dereference operator `*`, like this:

```rust
*i = 69;
```